# How to use javascript + user input to search for a google image and display it in html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, image

I'm trying to make a javascript function that when called, will take user input from a textbox and search google images with that input and get the link from the first image that comes up and then set it as the source for an image (I have not decided on the id for the image yet), any suggestions on how to do this would be much appricated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a site to get help with your existing code, not to help you design something that you haven't yet designed.  
If you don't have current code, nor do you know how you'd design this on paper regardless of code implementation, then you need to do some [additional research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), make an attempt and, if you still have trouble, come back with your code and explain what you have tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please outline the research you have done and where you are stuck with your coding. In particular, have you read the google documentation on this and what have you tried as a result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easy with this Node library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-search-google
Here is an example of the JS code:

```
    const imageSearch = require('image-search-google');
 
const client = new imageSearch('CSE ID', 'API KEY');
const options = {page:1};
client.search('APJ Abdul kalam', options)
    .then(images => {
        /*
        [{
            'url': item.link,
            'thumbnail':item.image.thumbnailLink,
            'snippet':item.title,
            'context': item.image.contextLink
        }]
         */
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error););
 
// search for certain size
client.search('Mahatma Gandhi', {size: 'large'});
 
// search for certain type
client.search('Indira Gandhi', {type: 'face'});
```

With the atribute url, you can generate an a tag with this URL.